# Class 'Magento\Setup\Mvc\Bootstrap\InitParamListener' not found when running CLI

Tags: magento-2.1, cli

I have a VM running Magento 2 with the sample data that was installed not using composer - I grabbed the latest version from the Magento site). The site itself runs fine, but when I try to run anything for the command line, I get this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Magento\Setup\Mvc\Bootstrap\InitParamListener' not found in /var/www/html/public/setup/config/application.config.php:24
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/public/vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php(57): require()
#1 /var/www/html/public/bin/magento(22): Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->__construct('Magento CLI')
#2 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/html/public/setup/config/application.config.php on line 24
```

I built the VM on another machine using build scripts, and then used those to build it on this machine, and it worked for a bit, but I suspect I left something out of source control that would be causing this.

Answer (score 2):

Check that the composer.json file in the Magento root directory is not corrupted / overwritten. You can compare it with the official composer.json file from https://github.com/magento/magento2

Answer (score 1):

I got a very similar issue with the following error;

`Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for Magento\Setup\Mvc\Bootstrap\InitParamListener`

I was able to solve this by deleting the contents of `vendor` and then re-running `composer install`

Answer (score -1):

I can see that something is running inside the vendor folder:

```
#0 /var/www/html/public/vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php(57)
```

Please, try:

```
composer self-update && composer update
```

Comment: I did that earlier and it wiped out my magento install. My composer.json only has this: {
    "repositories": {
        "magento": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://repo.magento.com"
        }
    }
}. I assume that has to do with the fact that I didn't use composer to install Magento?

Comment: Yes @Laura , probably. Sorry, I did not pay attention to the part of your question that had not used composer.. Got a solution for this?

Comment: This wiped out the entire Magento install